# Converting a String to an &str Rust without resulting in borrowing problem

Tags: rust

Is there someway to convert a String (function parameter) into &str (used in return value) while avoiding borrowing problems or referencing a temporary value.

Here is an example use case:

**PS: I am constrained by existing functions to these types and cannot just change the type of the function's parameter nor its &str consuming return value.
Also the following example uses clap::Arg::new to emphasize this aspect.**

```
// f is any iterator over String values, for example sake I am using Vec<String> with literal value which does not represent the real case.
let f: Vec<String> = vec!["A".into(),"B".into(),"C".into()].into_iter();

let arg: clap::Arg = f.map(|s: String|{
    clap::Arg::new(s.as_str())
});
```

Comment: I will say you're using a wrongly designed API, or in a wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there someway to convert a String (function parameter) into &str (used in return value) while avoiding borrowing problems or referencing a temporary value.

No but yes, but, really, no.

"No": if your parameter is a `String`, then the function owns the `String`, meaning once the function exits the `String` will be reclaimed, and so any referenced to that would be invalid as it would be dangling.

"but yes": you can convert the `String` into a `Box<str>`, which you can then [`leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak). This returns a `&'static str`, which will live forever

"but, really, no": while leaking memory is safe as far as Rust is concerned, it's still *leaking memory*. This might be fine in some contexts (e.g. short-running processes where explicitly freeing is a waste of resources, or some forms of ad-hoc interning), but in general it's really bad practice.

Comment: It is there a way to drop the value we leaked, in other words reverse the leak ?

Comment: No. You leaked the allocation, it's living forever now.